# Nginx MP3 Download 206 Partial Content HTTP Response

Tags: http, nginx, download, mp3

All:

I am successfully able to browse an MP3 website and play the MP3 streams without issue through Nginx (1.19.2).

However, when attempting to download an MP3 through Nginx, I'm receiving a 206 Partial Content HTTP Response:

```
192.168.0.154 - - [07/Nov/2020:10:25:22 +0000] "GET music.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 206 1982193 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.38"
```

A Client-Side Packet Trace shows the 206 Partial Content HTTP Response with a RST from Nginx:

```
3390    42.119998   192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 54  61978 → 80 [ACK] Seq=526 Ack=2293125 Win=1629440 Len=0
3391    42.120434   192.168.0.2 192.168.0.154   HTTP    347 HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content  (audio/mpeg)
3392    42.120449   192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 54  61978 → 80 [ACK] Seq=526 Ack=2293418 Win=1629184 Len=0
4375    69.116574   192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 54  [TCP Window Update] 61978 → 80 [ACK] Seq=526 Ack=2293418 Win=4219392 Len=0
4984    87.122995   192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 55  [TCP Keep-Alive] 61978 → 80 [ACK] Seq=525 Ack=2293418 Win=4219392 Len=1
4985    87.123324   192.168.0.2 192.168.0.154   TCP 66  [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 80 → 61978 [ACK] Seq=2293418 Ack=526 Win=6912 Len=0 SLE=525 SRE=526
5761    117.117822  192.168.0.2 192.168.0.154   TCP 60  80 → 61978 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2293418 Ack=526 Win=6912 Len=0
5762    117.117911  192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 54  61978 → 80 [ACK] Seq=526 Ack=2293419 Win=4219392 Len=0
7291    162.122574  192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 55  [TCP Keep-Alive] 61978 → 80 [ACK] Seq=525 Ack=2293419 Win=4219392 Len=1
7292    162.123048  192.168.0.2 192.168.0.154   TCP 60  [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 80 → 61978 [ACK] Seq=2293419 Ack=526 Win=6912 Len=0
7591    173.888730  192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TCP 54  61978 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=526 Ack=2293419 Win=4219392 Len=0
7594    173.889906  192.168.0.2 192.168.0.154   TCP 60  80 → 61978 [RST] Seq=2293419 Win=0 Len=0
```

I've tried several different browsers (i.e., Chrome, Edge, etc) with the same issue.

The download is successful when browsing directly and not using Nginx.

Any idea why the MP3 download is failing using Nginx?

Much Appreciated.

Gary

EDIT:

I discovered that the failing request is making a subsequent, asynchronous AJAX call to port 443 of Nginx where the connection is failing with "Certificate Unknown" against my self-signed certificate.

Click-Link Method:

```
GET http://example.com/ajax/inc/1488440 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://example.com/mp3/search?keywords=california+gurls
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: PHPSESSID=k6o4mq4np28bdr6n2g2pbgq190; zvAuth=1; zvLang=0; ZvcurrentVolume=100; nua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F86.0.4240.75%20Safari%2F537.36; asus_token=81G3BJcZjrt06SpsxUrh; z1_n=5

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.2
Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 07:38:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d3d5b5d9e0cbf7321ca040f0b126eb6631604821113; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-20 07:38:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Vary: Accept-Encoding
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 064863f2fb00000b786e0c5000000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=uoLAfVO2XqMqj6FJI%2BwyHFz52QFckDptxRfYjClxWfJvGUxnyAlsIR5Im37T5tC2j%2Big2WIgIfXajj0EWpPBMCxdTtC5ZA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
CF-RAY: 5eeda297ffb90b78-AMS
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

```
CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36

334 7.593054    192.168.0.154   192.168.0.2 TLSv1.2 61  Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Certificate Unknown)
```

I'd like to force the AJAX connection over port 80 of Nginx.  Is it possible to evaluate the Host header for :443 and if it exists change it to :80?  If so, what's the most efficient way to accomplish this task?

BTW...  I've already implemented the proxy_redirect https:// http://; directive, which works well for the URL but not for the Host header.

Thank you for your assistance.

Respectfully,

Gary

EDIT:

I've made some more progress in that when I copy/paste the AJAX URL into my browser's address-bar, the MP3 download request is successfully made and the MP3 is downloaded (opposed to the previous examples when I clicked on the MP3 download link).

Interestingly, the copy/paste method yields an initial 302 response opposed to a 200 response with the click-link method.

Copy/Paste Method:

```
GET http://example.com/ajax/inc/283544 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: PHPSESSID=k6o4mq4np28bdr6n2g2pbgq190; zvAuth=1; zvLang=0; ZvcurrentVolume=100; nua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F86.0.4240.75%20Safari%2F537.36; asus_token=81G3BJcZjrt06SpsxUrh; _zvBoobs_=%2F%2F_-%29

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.19.2
Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 14:27:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d2f42248bc953328459ea277d77ee62671604845673; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-20 14:27:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Location: http://example.com/download/283544
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 0649dab4e200000b6bce8a6000000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=SRYrhqPuwCUwe1MPbJ4RGW%2F8yqt4t8UD19zHwUrcNqX94%2FD8VZ6EW1vl2dogVCCaFkeDh3%2BCwogueN4i3K6Gc5SMenGqRg%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
CF-RAY: 5eeffa349c0d0b6b-AMS
Content-Length: 0
```

```
GET http://example.com/download/283544 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: PHPSESSID=k6o4mq4np28bdr6n2g2pbgq190; zvAuth=1; zvLang=0; ZvcurrentVolume=100; nua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F86.0.4240.75%20Safari%2F537.36; asus_token=81G3BJcZjrt06SpsxUrh; _zvBoobs_=%2F%2F_-%29

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Server: nginx/1.19.2
Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 14:27:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db70304f5ae41939e5d51647d5b3dcc261604845674; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-20 14:27:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Set-Cookie: _zvBoobs_=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: _zvBoobs_=%2F%2F_-%29; expires=Mon, 09-Nov-2020 02:27:54 GMT; Max-Age=43200; path=/; domain=.example.com
Location: http://st1.example.com/music/9/68/katy_perry_feat._snoop_dogg_-_california_gurls_(mstrkrft_remix_radio)_(zvukoff.ru).mp3?download=force
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 0649dab7760000faa08984d000000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=0RmfU9QT43xEgj9rH4LUrpCFAVXYh6gMubnObVJWjNxnSn4CJl5zkJVoeoD6uoEOkvVzgUOlwy%2F7KbFbat6NF8Qj0b64Ig%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
CF-RAY: 5eeffa38785bfaa0-AMS
Content-Length: 0
```

```
GET http://st1.example.com/music/9/68/katy_perry_feat._snoop_dogg_-_california_gurls_(mstrkrft_remix_radio)_(zvukoff.ru).mp3?download=force HTTP/1.1
Host: st1.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: zvAuth=1; zvLang=0; _zvBoobs_=%2F%2F_-%29

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.2
Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 14:28:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/force-download
Content-Length: 6634727
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Jul 2012 13:19:08 GMT
ETag: "501143cc-653ce7"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=katy_perry_feat._snoop_dogg_-_california_gurls_(mstrkrft_remix_radio)_(zvukoff.ru).mp3
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Nginx Access Logs (Click-Link Method - Fails):

```
192.168.0.154 - - [08/Nov/2020:14:27:00 +0000] "GET /ajax/inc/283544 HTTP/1.1" 200 94 "http://example.com/mp3/search?keywords=california+gurls" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.38"
```

Nginx Access Logs (Copy/Paste Method - Success):

```
192.168.0.154 - - [08/Nov/2020:14:27:53 +0000] "GET /ajax/inc/283544 HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
192.168.0.154 - - [08/Nov/2020:14:27:54 +0000] "GET /download/283544 HTTP/1.1" 307 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
192.168.0.154 - - [08/Nov/2020:14:28:31 +0000] "GET /music/9/68/katy_perry_feat._snoop_dogg_-_california_gurls_(mstrkrft_remix_radio)_(zvukoff.ru).mp3?download=force HTTP/1.1" 200 6634727 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
```

I could use an extra set of eyes to review the requests/responses and nginx access logs to confirm whether I'm missing something.

The Click-Link and the Copy/Paste Methods are both going through the Nginx Reverse Proxy.

Much Appreciated.

Gary

EDIT:

I found the following in the body of the Click-Link 200 HTTP Response:

```
{"url":"https:\/\/example.com\/download\/2770587","isSuccess":1}
```

To me, it appears to be a Javascript redirect that Nginx is unaware of and in which the https protocol doesn't get rewritten to http.

Is it possible for Nginx to evaluate the body of a response and rewrite a given string (i.e., https => http)?

I think I might be able to use GreaseMonkey or the like to validate my theory.

Thanks, again, for your time and interest.

Respectfully,

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All:

That was it!  The subsequent, asynchronous AJAX call was responding with a Javascript redirect that was remedied using Nginx's sub_filter directive.

```
        location / {
            resolver 103.86.99.100;
            proxy_bind $server_addr;
            proxy_pass https://$host$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect https:// http://;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; # Needed by sub_filter to disable gzip compression
            sub_filter_types text/javascript text/css text/xml;
            sub_filter 'https:' 'http:';
            sub_filter_once off;
        }
```

The combination of disabling gzip compression, adding `sub_filter_types text/javascript`, and creating `sub_filter 'https:' 'http:'` rewrote the protocol of the Javascript redirect.

```
{"url":"http:\/\/z1.fm\/download\/3298838","isSuccess":1}
```

Then, I was able to download MP3's by simply clicking the AJAX link.